# Is there a way to enforce variable declarations in Python through coding style?

Tags: python, pycharm, coding-style

I'm using PyCharms to work on Python projects. I find that writing functions is easier when we declare the type of the function parameters or the type of the new variables declared explicitly. It also allows us to catch simple issues when we're calling the function incorrectly.

Is there a way to get the coding style to enforce variable/parameter type declaration?

Also does coding style apply only to the code that we're writing or is it possible that it might also throw errors on any imported libraries as well? Since, in Python the libraries are also Python source code which might get scrutinized by the IDE's coding style?

Comment: I am not sure if python has something that enforces it but your choices are to make a plugin or find a plugin that does so because python does not make it so you need to declare types of parameters.

Comment: Have you tried type hinting?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @TomerAriel Yes I've used that. But I'm interested in adding that to the coding style somehow. Or getting the code to let me know if I miss doing it somewhere.